# Time perception in dreams?

Tags: perception

Is time perception in dreams the same as time perception in waking life? There was an experiment that showed it was roughly true, (10 seconds in the dream is around 12 in real life), what causes this change in time perception? Also, why do people have dreams that seem to last weeks? Does the brain just skip over details?

Experiment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3893623/

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/8386/7001